# Bootstrap Advanced Dropdown Search

Tags: html, css, django-bootstrap3

I want to create a search bar equivalent to this one:

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/advanced-dropdown-search

But the problem in this example is that if the user writes only in the first input text box, no action is called. How can I fix it? I tried to add a form that that input but then the drop-down button goes out of place.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the action you're referring to here is the "form submit".

If you look at the HTML, the only "submit" button here is the button with the search icon in the dropdown.

```
                             ...
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="contain">Contains the words</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
                              </div>
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                            </form>
                            ...
```

The button that is visible next to the search text input "Search for snippets" is just a regular button which will not perform any action.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
```

This is really just a UI example, where the expectation is that you'll write the javascript and performance functions to be associated.

If you just want the simple submit action, I'd remove the submit button in the dropdown and change the visible button to a submit button. You would also have to move the closing  tag to wrap the action into the form.